# Can i deploy a Django project using Apache that is not located in /var/www?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Django project which is working in development on my local machine.

I am confused whether or not I am able to have my django project in another directory other than /var/www/. Do I just need to change the DocumentRoot in the apache config file?

Thanks

Comment: basically yes, be sure to start and stop the server after applying each change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DocumentRoot` should not be set to be a directory containing your project code as it risks making your code downloadable.

So yes you can change what `DocumentRoot` refers to, but usually you do not need to if Django application mounted at the root of the site as Django hides whatever was in the original directory specified by `DocumentRoot`.

Just set `WSGIScriptAlias` to WSGI script file for the Django application as explained in the Django documentation.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

If what the documentation tells you isn't doing what you think you need, then ask a specific question about your problem and properly explain what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Thanks, so once I have done this basic configuration - how do i get apache to 'point' at my django project. When I type in my servers IP address it comes up with the apache index.html, but I obviously want to run my django server and have that appear when I type in my servers IP

Comment: Sounds like you may have created a separate ``VirtualHost`` and added the configuration to that. If that is the case, you need to use the hostname that you set as ``ServerName`` in the new ``VirtualHost`` (cannot be an IP). Add the configuration you are using to your question as an edit.